# Service Discovery on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-simpledb

does anyone have suggestions for dynamic service discovery on Amazon AWS?

I am thinking about ZooKeeper but would like an approch that do not require running VM's.

Comment: Take a look here http://saipraveenblog.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/service-discovery-in-soamsa/

Answer (score 6):

Check out Netflix's [curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator) project.

It is a framework, client, and recipe wrapper around [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

One of the extensions is [Service Discovery](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Service-Discovery).

> **What Is a Discovery Service?**
>
> In SOA/distributed systems, services need to find each other. i.e. a
>   web service might need to find a caching service, etc. DNS can be used
>   for this but it is nowhere near flexible enough for services that are
>   constantly changing. A Service Discovery system provides a mechanism
>   for:
>
> - Services to register their availability
> - Locating a single instance of a particular service
> - Notifying when the instances of a service change

curator Service Discovery enables:

- Registering/Unregistering Services
- Querying for Services
- Service Cache

Comment: Curator is extremely well-designed and relatively easy to get started with. I definitely second the recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean service discovery......you can use udp and whatever you need and broadcasting in a VPC to "discover" whatever you need and comes online.  What does zookeeper(a system for helping to distributed transactions) have to do with service discovery.

Comment: Broadcast and multicast doesn't work in EC2.  You might get it in a VPC, but as far as I can tell, this isn't supported yet.

Comment: @TedDunning is right. Neither EC2 nor VPC allows multi/broadcasting >> [VPC Current Limitations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html#CurrentCapabilities)